# sublist groups of tuples with same values

Tags: python, group-by, tuples, sublist

I have the following list:

```
o = [([1,1,1,1],[0.9,0.2,0.2,0.3]),([1,1,1],[0.7,0.6,0.7]),([1,1],[0.8,0.3]),([2,2,2,2,2],[0.8,0.9,0.2,0.3,0.1]),([2,2],[0.2,0.7]),([3,3,3],[0.9,0.4,0.3]),([3,3],[0.1,0.1]),([3,3,3,3],[0.9,0.4,0.3,0.1]),([4,4],[0.1,0.3]),([4,4],[0.6,0.7]),([4,4,4],[0.3,0.1,0.1])]
```

This is the desired output:

```
output = [[([1,1,1,1],[0.9,0.2,0.2,0.3]),([1,1,1],[0.7,0.6,0.7]),([1,1],[0.8,0.3])],
[([2,2,2,2,2],[0.8,0.9,0.2,0.3,0.1]),([2,2],[0.2,0.7])],
[([3,3,3],[0.9,0.4,0.3]),([3,3],[0.1,0.1]),([3,3,3,3],[0.9,0.4,0.3,0.1])],
[([4,4],[0.1,0.3]),([4,4],[0.6,0.7]),([4,4,4],[0.3,0.1,0.1])]]
```

I want to create sublists from the initial list, grouped by the first element of each tuple being equal.
This is what I did so far, but I don't know how to get the sublists as shown above.

```
x=[]
for i in range(len(o)-1):
    if o[i][0][0] == o[i+1][0][0]:
        x.append(o[i])
    else:
        x[-1].append(o[i])
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are the tuples that start with same thing alwaysnext to each other in o?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=[]
for i_o in range(len(o)):
    for i_x in range(len(x)):
        if o[i_o][0][0]==x[i_x][0][0][0]:
            x[i_x].append(o[i_o])
            break
    else:
        x.append([o[i_o]])
```